# create a refresh button for Text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I am trying to create a refresh button for my model.id in  html helper. I am working on ERP project so multiple peoples will use the application so i need refresh button So i tried this
**MVC**enter code here

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new { id="code", @class = "form-control "})
<button id="button1" style="border: none;width: 50px;height: 50px;" value="Refresh"><i class="fas fa-sync"></i></button>
```

**javascript---**

```
 $("#button1").click(function (event) {
        alert('Clicked')
        $("#code").val('model.Id')
    });
```

but this is not working please give some suggestionsenter code here

Comment: use document.on('click') intead of click

Comment: It looks like you're trying to refresh *from the server* (*"multiple people using the application"*) - is that the case?   Sounds like you need to make an ajax call to get the latest value

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to add a new `data` attribute to the element in your `EditorFor` which displays the value. This attribute should hold the starting value of the control. Then in your JS, when the 'refresh' button is clicked, set the current value back to the original, like this:

```js
$("#button1").click(function(e) {
  $("#code").val(function() {
    return $(this).data('original-value');
  });
});
```

```css
#button1 {
  border: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new { id="code", @class = "form-control", }) -->
<input type="text" id="code" data-original-value="foobar" value="foobar" />
<button id="button1" value="Refresh"><i class="fas fa-sync"></i> Refresh</button>
```

Comment: what is original-value ,

Comment: The data attribute I described, and added to the element in the example.